# Generate 10 Byte HEX from string in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to generate 10 Byte HEX from any string in Android. I want to generate this hex value from username and write this HEX value in my hardware .

Comment: hmm. Sure, Why not. i really appreciate your help

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: For a `Fix 10 Byte HEX` string you dont need something else. Just define it once and use it. I read 'fixed'. I think you need to reformulate. Do you mean 'generate a ten byte hex string from another string'?

Comment: Your password needs to be at least five characters. Then just take the hex representation of the first five byte values. That will give ten hex characters.